# Py2Neo Merge using multiple property keys

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have been trying to use the merge method to create a node using the Py2Neo driver but am having issues.

I try `tx.merge(a,"Person",('name','age'))` but get the error: TypeError: tuple

In the merge documentation: [here](http://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Transaction.merge) it says "Note that multiple property keys may be specified by using a tuple." Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same issue lately, and after reading through the source code provided in the documentation, I've come to the conclusion that the py2neo is wrong with it says that "multiple keys may be specified by using a tuple" as no matter which `merge()` you call (mostly because they're almost the same, except `Graph.merge` uses `Transaction`'s autocommit value) it only allows 1 key and doesn't like the tuple type.

As an alternative, you can use a py2neo function that directly executes a Cypher `MERGE` query to include whatever nodes you're trying to create/merge (ex. `Graph.run("MERGE (:Node {...})")`). Unfortunately this doesn't really solve the issue, but this might not be in our hands.

Comment: If this is an error in py2neo's docs or implementation, have you considered raising an issue on [py2neo's GitHub repo](https://github.com/technige/py2neo)?

Comment: Looks like merging by multiple keys is no longer supported: [this issue](https://github.com/technige/py2neo/issues/675)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem in different context; I solved with..

```
a = Node("Person", name, age)
a.__primarylabel__ = "Person"
a.__primarykey__ = "name"
#a.__primarykey__ = "age"
tx.merge(a) # used graph.merge(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with the arguments to the merge function. Perhaps try:

```
tx.merge(a, primary_label='Person', primary_key=('name', 'age'))
```

Also note there are two different methods for `merge` functions in the documentation. See the difference between these two links:

http://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph.merge
http://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Transaction.merge

Comment: Tried that too. Same error. And i've tried both graph.merge() and tx.merge() and get the same error. I've also tried tx.merge(a) and get the error: ValueError: Primary label and primary key are required for MERGE operation. Not sure what else to try

Comment: Perhaps try creating a node first before passing it to the merge function. See the following example: https://github.com/technige/py2neo/issues/594

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have this `d = {'name': 'foo', 'age': 'bar'}`
`a = Node("Person", **d)`
`tx.merge(a)`

This gives me error: ValueError: Primary label and primary key are required for MERGE operation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it doesn't work with multiple keys but just one works like this:

```
        topic = Node("Topic", 
            cname=cname, 
            name=name
        )

        graph.merge(
            topic, "Topic", "name"
        )
```

where name is the `key` to merge on.

v4 docs
https://py2neo.org/v4/database.html?highlight=merge#py2neo.database.Graph.merge